Is self-imposed tza'ar in a sukkah considered tza'ar?
The prime example of "tza'ar" that would exempt one from a sukkah is rain. If one had a sprinkler that shot water into his sukkah and that leads to enough "rain" that a person would be patur from the sukkah, is that a valid p'tur? (The situation could be as innocent as someone forgetting to turn off his automatic sprinkler that waters his garden and his Sukkah happens to be in the path - there aren't necessarily negative intentions)

How about "this minimum size Sukkah is too cramped and I'm uncomfortable"

See Shulchan Aruch and Magen Avraham (OC 640:3). The implication is that if there was a degree of negligence involved it would not exempt, but if there was a valid reason to have the tza'ar then it would even though it's self inflicted

@AKA Where would the line be drawn on negligence? For example, if I look at the weather forecast for Sukkos for a location and see non-stop rain, and then decide to go there for Sukkos (either because of the weather or otherwise) is that negligence? In other words, should I consider typical weather patterns/weather forecasts when deciding where to be for Sukkos?

In such a case the worry might not even be whether one is obligated to sit in the Sukkah; it might be whether a Sukkah that is uncomfortable to that extent is kosher in the first place.

I get the question but I think the example is weak. Why don't you just go to another sukkah?

@Chani Excellent! That leads to a different question. There are some places where rainfall is so localized, like South Florida, where it could be pouring on one block and perfectly dry on a different one. It sounds ridiculous if you don't know what I'm talking about, but trust me - it really happens. So, if it's raining where I am do I have to walk around town to a place where it's not raining?

@Michael I would say that would depend on whether you've got a decent reason to be there specifically on Sukkos - if you do it would be fine and not called negligence (see the MA's wording there)
